# Have you recently discouraged using naviation component?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation, android-bottomnavigationview

I am using `bottom navigation` for `single activity`.

What I'm trying to do is do various screen transitions through the `bottom menu` (`fragment`).
And we are implementing a function to switch screens without moving the menu on the switched screen.

I've considered using the `BottomNavigation Activity` provided by Android (probably the `JetPack navigation component`).

However, I saw that there were many problems with this component. Especially the `NavController`.

For example, when i switch screens and then come back, i have to manually restore the view state.

Because `NavController` uses `replace()` instead of `show/hide`, so I've been told so

In addition to these problems, using `FragmentManager` and `show/hide` is more recommended, is it true?

So I'm currently using `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener`, but it's actually more difficult because I'm implementing the screen transition myself.

Comment: Views automatically save and restore their own state as per [Saving View State](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state#view) - you can verify this by looking at any `EditText` with an `android:id`. You'd need to do this anyways to support configuration changes and process death and recreation - it isn't an optional thing you can ignore in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely use the provided NavController if I was you.

It has had its issues over the years, some of them which you are describing. Most of these problems were removed in [version 2.4.0-alpha01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.4.0-alpha01). Version 2.4.0-alpha02 is also out now.

Check out [this](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/main/NavigationAdvancedSample) sample to see the BottomNavigationView in action, together with the new NavController. It is a great starting point for any app.

Comment: thank you. But the link is an alpha version. In other words, it is a trial version rather than a full version. Is it okay to use it?

Comment: It should be okay to use it. I have personally used version 2.4.0-alpha02 ever since it came out, and I have not encountered any issues. I think implementing everything from scratch will be more prone to errors